# Beginner Level Question Django 3.0: Class based views

Tags: django, django-templates

I am stuck at some beginner level concept of django. I am so much unable to understand documentation of `TemplateView`. 
In following sample of code:

```
class ProductView(TemplateView):
     template_name = "product.html"
```

Form just `template_name` how django render html page. I mean is `template_name` is reserved keyword? What if I write `template_name1` instead of it will it work? And I am not returning anything how this single doing all things.

Comment: go through the related document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView

Answer (score 1):

This website has it all https://ccbv.co.uk/
And why it's not returning anything ? 
That's the point of class based views
It does all the magic for you so you dont need to worry about it.
Well if you actually want to worry You can use functions instead or browse the website above and you will know what magic I'm talking about